# Logging CSI into file 802.11n

Tags: 802.11n

I have followed the steps in this [link](http://dhalperi.github.com/linux-80211n-csitool/installation.html) and i am trying the last steps to log data using

```
sudo ./log_to_file tmp.dat
```

command, and I left it for 3 hours but only 10 traces were written in the file

I am using hp Elitebook 6930p laptop with Intel 5300 card and Cisco linksys X2000 access point

Does anybody know a solution for this problem ?